# XML not written fully

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a problem with some XML files.

I have about 500+ text files which i read from and extract data and export it to an XML. However, the XML generated is truncated halfway.

```
<Maps>

<Location> 

</Location>

<Locat
```

It truncates somewhat like that. When i try to open it in notepad, it seems to use up the whole page of notepad. Could it be due to a memory issue since i have quite a large amount of data. Is there any work around on it.  I am running the program on a VM

```
private XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("Maps.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program prog = new Program();
            String[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"maps_new");
            prog.writer.WriteStartDocument();
            prog.writer.WriteStartElement("Maps");
            foreach (String file in filenames)
            {
                prog.extractToXML(file);
            }
            prog.writer.WriteEndElement();    
            prog.writer.WriteEndDocument();

        }
public void extractToXML(String filename)
        {
            XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;

            XPathDocument xmldoc = new XPathDocument(filename);
            XPathNavigator nav = xmldoc.CreateNavigator();
            String query = "//Schema/@tree";
            NodeIter = nav.Select(query);
            writer.WriteStartElement("file");

            writer.WriteStartAttribute("name");
            writer.WriteString(extractFileName(filename));
            writer.WriteEndAttribute();

            while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("type");
                writer.WriteString(extractFileName(NodeIter.Current.Value.ToString()));
                writer.WriteEndElement();            
            }

            NodeIter = nav.Select("//Location");
            while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Location");
                writer.WriteString(NodeIter.Current.Value.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
```

Comment: what is your code for this conversion? Post it here, it will be useful!

Comment: try notepad++ instead of notepad. maybe the text file is not valid xml?

Comment: Seems like a truncated stream because Flush() wasn't called where it should be.

Comment: @omerschleifer yes notepad++ doesnt work either though it reads more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a writer, be sure to `Close` it when you are done:

try addind this:

```
   //rest of code omitted
    foreach (String file in filenames)
    {
      prog.extractToXML(file);
    }
    prog.writer.WriteEndElement();    
    prog.writer.WriteEndDocument();

    prog.writer.Flush(); //<-- here
    prog.writer.Close(); //<-- and here
```

and better yet: use a `using` statement and make `extractToXML` static:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   using(var writer = new XmlTextWriter("Maps.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
   {
     String[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(@"maps_new");
     writer.WriteStartDocument();
     writer.WriteStartElement("Maps");
     foreach (String file in filenames)
     {
        extractToXML(file, writer);
     }
     writer.WriteEndElement();    
     writer.WriteEndDocument();

     writer.Flush();
     writer.Close();
   }
}
public static void extractToXML(String filename, XmlTextWriter wirter)
{
    XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;

    XPathDocument xmldoc = new XPathDocument(filename);
    XPathNavigator nav = xmldoc.CreateNavigator();
    String query = "//Schema/@tree";
    NodeIter = nav.Select(query);
    writer.WriteStartElement("file");

    writer.WriteStartAttribute("name");
    writer.WriteString(extractFileName(filename));
    writer.WriteEndAttribute();

    while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("type");
        writer.WriteString(extractFileName(NodeIter.Current.Value.ToString()));
        writer.WriteEndElement();            
    }

    NodeIter = nav.Select("//Location");
    while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Location");
        writer.WriteString(NodeIter.Current.Value.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Comment: `Dispose` calls `Close`, `Close` calls `Flush`. Calling all three manually is just confusing and can start a cargo cult.

Comment: @adrianm Im aware of that dispose does :) I left the two method calls in place to be expliced about closing the stream.